# Helm convert data for nginx template

Tags: json, nginx, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Im using the following file by helm

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-cfg
data:
  default.conf: |-
  {{ .Files.Get "config/nginx.conf" | nindent 4 }}
```

and I got the following error:

**Error: YAML parse error on ops/templates/config/nginx.conf: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context**

The nginx file looks like following

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name: {{ print "kiftb." .Values.global.host | quote }} // this is the error line
...
```

The line with the `sever_name` create the error.

Any idea how to solve it?

**update**

As suggested by @Evan I've tried to remove the colon,

```
server_name {{ print "kiftb." .Values.global.host | quote }}
```

And I got an error:

```
error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead
helm.go:81: [debug] error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead
```

Any Idea how to overcome this? is there any workaround ?

Comment: A good place to validate yaml files http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: @user5756014 - this is not the problem, the issue is using the helm value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the colon after `server_name`.

```
server_name {{ print "kiftb." .Values.global.host | quote }}
```

...

Comment: Thanks I try it out and I got diffrent error: `error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead` and idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Alberto Sorry I did not identify this before, but I think you are operating on a flawed premise. Helm [does not support the rendering of non-yaml files](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7899), and that's also why you were getting that error before. Your first issue seemed to be from Helm parsing the conf file as if it was a yaml file (although the colon was actually invalid syntax for conf files). You seem to be approaching the problem in the wrong way, so I would look into however the [actual ngnix chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx) does it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you put the conf file in a wrong path. Helm deals with all the files inside `${chart_path}/templates/` as template or tpl files, which should be composed in YAML file. So basically you are facing the issue that helm are trying to parse `ops/templates/config/nginx.conf` as a template file, and definitely it will fail.
The solution would be: move your conf file out of the path `ops/templates`, use `ops/config/nginx.conf` would be fine, and you even do not need change anything in your configmap script, it will work.